# stack overflow (recursion too deep) error in go procedure

Tags: netlogo

When I run my code, I sometimes get the following error:

```
stack overflow (recursion too deep)
  error while observer running ASK
  called by procedure GO
  called by Button 'go'
```

This only happens intermittently and I'm not sure what causes it.

```
to go 
ask cars [
speed-up
fd speed
if([pcolor] of patch-ahead 1 = yellow)
[stay]

 ]


 tick
 end

 to speed-up
  let car-ahead one-of turtles-on patch-ahead 3
 ifelse car-ahead != nobody
  [ slow-down-car car-ahead ]
  [ speed-up-car ]
  if speed < speed-min [ set speed speed-min ]
  if speed > speed-limit [ set speed speed-limit ]
  fd speed
  separate-cars

 end
 to separate-cars ;; turtle procedure
    if any? other turtles-here [
    fd 3
   separate-cars
  ]
 end

to stay
  set speed 0
ask cars
[


   ifelse  count-up = 0 [speed-up
 fd speed
   set color green

 ] [  set count-up  count-up - 1
   stay ]
  ]
 end

to slow-down-car [ car-ahead ] ;; turtle procedure
;; slow down so you are driving more slowly than the car ahead of you
set speed [ speed ] of car-ahead - deceleration
 end

to speed-up-car ;; turtle procedure
  set speed speed + acceleration
end
```

Comment: note : am trying to make cars stop on yellow patches and decrease the count-up until it reaches 0 and only after that it continue moving forward

Comment: You are calling `separate-cars` within `separate-cars`, which means each car is calling that function which calls that function which calls that function, etc. Try removing that line from within the procedure.

Comment: nope it;s still the same error i tried that :(

Comment: Hm. It looks like you also have `stay` called within `stay`. Additionally, you have `ask cars` in `go`, but then `ask cars` in `stay`- as a baseline, you should have only one `ask cars` unless you want all cars to ask all cars. Can you make this into a reproducible example ([see MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))? It's hard to test your code as there are missing chunks.

Comment: i tried that but it keeps running non stop !

Comment: here is my full code if you can try it and tell my what's wrong

Comment: i didn't know how to but my full code . sorry 
any way the problem is still not solved :(

Comment: breed [cars car]
breed [gas_stations gas_station]

gas_stations-own[
  state?]

cars-own [
    speed
  speed-limit
  speed-min
   Wtime
   extra-load
   count-up
   state
]

to setup
  clear-all
  ask patches [ setup-road ]
 create-gas_stations 1 [
    set shape "gas"
    set size 5
    set color red
    set xcor 25 set ycor 5
     set heading 90


    set state? true
  ]
 setup-cars

  reset-ticks
end

Comment: to setup-road ;; patch procedure
  ifelse pycor < 4 and pycor > -4 [set pcolor black ]
  [set pcolor green ]
   if pycor < 3 and pycor > -3 [ set pcolor gray ]
  if pycor > -3 and pycor < 3 and pxcor > 23 and pxcor < 27
  [set pcolor yellow ]

end
to enter-cars 
  
  repeat 10 [ setup-cars wait 1]
  
end


to setup-cars

  create-cars 1 [
    set color red
    set xcor -29
     set shape "car"
    set size 3
    set Wtime 0
   set heading 90
   set speed 0.1 + random-float 0.9
    set speed-limit 1
    set speed-min 0

Comment: set extra-load one-of [ 0 1 2 3 4  ]
    set state one-of [ 0 0.25 0.75 0.50 ]
     set wtime ( 5 - ( 5 * state ) ) + ( extra-load )

  set count-up wtime
  ]

end

Comment: this is the first part of the code that is missing in my code in the question > i hope you can help me

Comment: You should just edit your original question (there is a button to edit near the bottom of the question) otherwise it's going to be too dense for users to sort out. Please have a look at the [asking guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for some tips on how to ask questions effectively and how to format your questions.